# PHP illegal offset type error

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object

Getting an **illegal offset type** error on this line in the second foreach loop.

```
$userlist[$user]->addPeriod($period);
```

Made some changes from past info given in past threads and this is the new version of the code. There is also a warning but I think that might be resolved if the error is resolved:

> Call to a member function addPeriod() on a non-object

```
$periods_arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$subPeriods_arr = array(1, 2);
$questionslist = array("q_1_1", "q_1_2", "q_2_1", "q_2_2", "q_3_1", "q_4_1", "q_5_1");

class User {
    public $userId;
    public $periods = array();

    public function __construct($number)
    {
        $this->userId = $number;
    }

    public function addPeriod($pno)
    {
        $this->periods[] = new Period($pno);
    }
}

class Period {
    public $periodNo;
    public $subPeriods = array();

    public function __construct($number)
    {
        $this->periodNo = $number;
    }

    public function addSubPeriod($spno)
    {
        $this->subPeriods[] = new SubPeriod($spno);
    }
}

class SubPeriod {
    public $SubPeriodNo;
    public $answers = array();

    public function __construct($number)
    {
        $this->SubPeriodNo = $number;
    }

    public function addAnswer($answer)
    {
        $this->answers[] = new Question($answer);
    }
}

class Question {
    public $answer;

    public function __construct($ans)
    {
        $this->answer = $ans;
    }

    public function getAnswer()
    {
        echo $answer;   
    }
}        

$userlist = array();

$sql = 'SELECT user_ref FROM _survey_1_as GROUP BY user_ref ORDER BY user_ref ASC';
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $userlist[] = new User($row['user_ref']);
}

foreach ($userlist as &$user)
{
    foreach ($periods_arr as &$period)
    {
        $userlist[$user]->addPeriod($period);

        foreach ($subPeriods_arr as &$subPeriod)
        {

            $userlist[$user]->periods[$period]->addSubPeriod($subPeriod);

            foreach($questionslist as &$aquestion)
            {
                $sql = 'SELECT ' . $aquestion . ' FROM _survey_1_as WHERE user_ref = ' .
                     $user . ' AND answer_sub_period = ' . $subPeriod . ' AND answer_period = ' . $period .''; 

                $result = mysql_query($sql);

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $userlist[$user]->periods[$period]->subPeriods[$subPeriod]->addAnswer($row[$questionNumber]);
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}

$userlist[3]->periods[3]->subPeriods[1]->getAnswer();
```

Comment: You may have this issue: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29992 It is best to remove references and use `foreach ($periods_arr as $period_key => $period)`

Comment: does this mean adding another dimension to my arrays(all of them)?

Comment: I counted 5 nested loop!You should refactor this block of code

Comment: @meda yeh prob should look into that once i get her working first :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `$user` as a key into your `$userlist` array, but you're fetching it as a value.  Try something like this:

```
foreach ($userlist as $user => $userVal)
{
    ...
    $userlist[$user]->addPeriod($period);
}
```

This makes `$user` the key into your `$userlist` array.

It would be even clearer to do something like this:

```
foreach ($userlist as $user)
{
}
```

And then don't use `$user` as a key into your array, but just use `$user` as the value.  For example:

```
$user->addPeriod($period);
...
$user->periods[$period]->addSubPeriod($subPeriod);
```

Comment: done that for the next loop here `$user->periods[$period]->addSubPeriod($subPeriod);` and now getting undefined offset

Comment: You're doing the same with with your `$periods_arr`.  Just apply the lessons learned from the above answer to the other loops you're using.

Comment: but $period on the line that now erroring is a key right? so i can't really fetch it as a value? bit lost and making changes to a legacy app that the rest of is spaghetti code -.-

Comment: If you can't solve the new error you're getting, then post a new question about it.

Comment: kk will have to wait 90 minutes though. see if i can fix it before then :p thanks for your help

Comment: just done this
`if (isset($user->periods[$period])) 
{ 
   $user->periods[$period]->addSubPeriod($subPeriod);
}`

seems to work a bit better now getting an error in the sql query saying $user can't be converted to string which I thought is a string? but anyway thats another problem. 
Should i be stopping the loop and move on to the next $user if its not set?

Comment: @user3677941 `$user` is an object, not a string.  That's why you can call functions on it.

Comment: @user3677941   You shouldn't use your `isset` solution because you're `foreach`ing over your `$periods_arr` array, but trying to use the values as keys into your `$user->periods` arrays.  You aren't guaranteed that those arrays match, or that you aren't missing some values in their difference.